# What is the best way to append lists inside a dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to build a list that has 1 key to many values. The best way I can think to do this is by pointing a key value to a list. However, I am having trouble building the lists inside the dict.

```
num_items = len(decoded_data['data']['arrivalsAndDepartures'])
buses = list()
busdict = dict()
val = list() 
for i in range(num_items):
  decoded_data['data']['arrivalsAndDepartures']
  bus = decoded_data['data']['arrivalsAndDepartures'][i]['routeId']
   buses.append(bus)
   try:
     busdict[bus]
   except KeyError:
    busdict[bus] = [i]
    print("except "+  bus , str(i))
   else:
    val = busdict[bus]
    busdict[bus] = [val].append(i)
    print("else "+ bus ,val, str(i))
```

This gives me weird results.

> $ python test.py  
>   except 40_590 0 
>   except 40_554 1 
>   except 40_592 2 
>   else 40_590 [0] 3 
>   except 1_122 4 
>   except 40_577 5 
>   else 40_590 None 6

From the above test result, the third time it hits the key '40_590' the value is cleared.

Comment: Try to use defaultdict. Example: from collections import defaultdict;  d =defaultdict(list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
busdict[bus] = [val].append(i)
```

`list.append` is an inplace operation and returns `None`. So, you are clearing the previously stored list in it. You could fix it like this

```
busdict[bus].append(i)
```

But the best way to solve this problem is by using [`dict.setdefault`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) function (which assigns and returns the default value if the specified key is not found), like this

```
busdict.setdefault(bus, []).append(i)
```

But the best way to solve this problem would be to use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
busdict = defaultdict(list)
...
...
busdict[bus].append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks both worked exactly the same. I appreciate your quick response to this.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` does not return a value. Use it like this:

```
   else:
    val = busdict[bus].append(i)
    print("else "+ bus ,val, str(i))
```

By the way: [use four spaces for indents](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)!